# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

Tags: java, hadoop, filesystems

I keep getting this error.I've included the hadoop commons and the core libs in the classpath but still i keep getting this error.Help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Where do you run your code?

Comment: i run it in my localhost

Comment: Do run it in eclipse or in a tomcat or from command line?

Comment: @Jens ran it in eclipse   ..
Now it gives this error 
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader:
 Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

**java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation**
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:214)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2559)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2569) ....

Comment: @Jens i got the **classNotFound** error  when i ran it from command line with the help of maven

Comment: I run it on apache tomcat? is there any issue with that?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? There is no answer accepted here.

Answer (score 17):

Here's how to troubleshoot:  Look inside the jar that you're executing to see if that class file is actually there:

```
jar tvf target/my-jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep hadoop/conf/Configuration.class
```

If it's not, you need to add it to your classpath or change the way your jar is packaged.

Are you using Maven or some similar build tool?  You may have a dependency with a 'scope', which means that it will only be compiled into your jar in certain circumstances.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In this example, the scope tag tells Maven that you're using this dependency for building, but it indicates that the dependency will be provided during runtime, so you'll either need to remove this tag or add the hadoop jar using `-cp=/path/to/jar.jar` during runtime.  Another example of a scope like this is 'test', which indicates that the jar is only needed in the path during unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the classpath in your jar. You can check it like mark said;

```
jar tvf target/my-jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep hadoop/conf/Configuration.class
```

Answer (score -2):

add dependency to `hadoop-core`.

Comment: Read the post: the OP already has the core libs in the classpath.